# Git: removing commits permanently on local and remote

Tags: git

I tried to remove all the new commits (about 10) of them and revert the branch to a previous commit.

I want to remove all the history as well locally and remotely.

The command I tried to do is:

```
git reset --hard 6a0123456787f1dabcde46b49b
```

This does reset my local branch to the previous commit. However, since my local is not in line with the remote, Git does not allow me to push this to the remote branch.

If I run:

```
git push origin master
```

It fails and asked me to pull from master before push.

If I do the "pull", it will put my branch to the state before I reset.

My question is that how can I push the reseted version of my branch? Or is there any other ways to remove commits from both local and remote branches?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

git push origin master -f

Be careful,  it will replace your remote branch.